# Install APC on PHP For Windows 7 x64

Tags: php, apache, windows-7, apc

When I try to start Apache with

```
[PHP_APC]    
extension = php_apc.dll
[apc]
apc.shm_segments=1
apc.optimization=0
apc.shm_size=128
apc.ttl=7200
apc.user_ttl=7200
apc.num_files_hint=1024
apc.mmap_file_mask=/tmp/apc.XXXXXX
apc.enable_cli=1
```

in php.ini, it fails.  I have the php_apc.dll in the ext directory.

Using Apache 2.2.17 and PHP 5.2.14 on Windows 7 x64.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed. Was using the wrong version of APC.

Comment: any chance of reveiling which version you used?

Comment: @Populus I had the same issue. I used [version 3.1.5-5.3](http://downloads.php.net/pierre/php_apc-3.1.5-5.3-vc9-x86.zip)

Answer (score 4):

After trying a lot of solutions, I found one that worked for me... so I am going to post this as an answer just to help people that may have the same problem finding the correct version to use.

I am using **Windows 7 32bits**, **PHP 5.3.13**, **Apache 2.2.22**, and the `php_apc.dll` found in the file `apc-igbinary-fastlz-snap20110301-5.3-ts-vc9-x86.zip` in this site: http://downloads.php.net/pierre/

I have registered the extension by just pasting the following code to the end of `php.ini` file:

```
[PHP_APC]
extension=php_apc.dll
```

Then I checked the result of phpinfo(), by using this php file:

*phpinfo.php*

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Comment: It seems that it's not possible to list the directory anymore... though the file is still there: http://downloads.php.net/pierre/apc-igbinary-fastlz-snap20110301-5.3-ts-vc9-x86.zip

Answer (score 1):

Best bet, due to the limited windows PECL support atm, is to install Zend Server CE w/ PHP 5.3. You can have it install itself on IIS or Apache on the windows machine. Zend Server comes with APC built in (As well as many other PHP modules missing from the current 5.3 PECL stack).

As a side note, you could probably (I haven't tested this so...is just a possibility) install the server, "steal" the dlls, and install PHP however you like w/o zend server. BUT, that said, Zend server is actually pretty nice :)

Comment: Meh, my answer was focused on PHP 5.3 (which has pecl issues), not 5.2. My appologies.

Comment: I also switched over to Zend Server and it runs better than my previous php setup. Thx for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

when on Windows use APC VC6 from here 
http://downloads.php.net/pierre